# Highcharts xaxis is off by several hours

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I'm pulling values from a MySQL database using PHP, and attempting to plot them using Highcharts.  The problem I'm finding is the xaxis values seems to be off by 4 hours.  Searching through past threads, some people place the useUTC: false in the global chart options, but it did not seem to work for me.

`global:{
useUTC: false
}`

Here is the code I'm using to set up the chart.  I'm a javascript newbie, so it's very possible I did something stupid in here.  Any suggestions?

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Temperature Data from XBee</title>

        <script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script> 

        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
                chart: {
                        renderTo: 'container',
                        type: 'line',
                        marginRight: 130,
                        marginBottom: 25
                    },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Wireless Sensor Data: Temperature (F)',
                            x: -20 //center
                    },
                global: {
                    useUTC: false
                    },

                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'temperature'
                            },
                    type: 'double',
                    min: 0,

                   },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'time'
                            },
                    type: 'datetime'                
                   },

                 series: [{             
                    name: 'Temperature',
                    data: []
                     }]
                }

            $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
                options.series[0].data = json;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
                });
            });   

        </script>

        <script src="js/highcharts.js"></script>    
        <script src="js/themes/grid-light.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="min-width: 800px; height: 800px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP code that queries the database and puts the data into the JSON format.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","raspberry");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xbee", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, temperature FROM data WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    extract($r);
    $time = strtotime($r[0]);
    $time *=1000;
    $row[0] = $time;
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is what my JSON format looks like.

```
 [[1414172722000,73.4],[1414172727000,73.4],[1414172732000,73.4],[1414172737000,75.2],[1414172742000,75.2],[1414172747000,75.2],[1414172753000,73.4],[1414172758000,75.2],[1414172763000,73.4],[1414172768000,75.2],[1414172773000,75.2],[1414172778000,75.2],[1414172783000,75.2],[1414172788000,73.4],[1414172793000,73.4],[1414172798000,75.2],[1414172803000,75.2],[1414172809000,75.2],[1414172814000,75.2],[1414172819000,75.2],[1414172824000,73.4],[1414172829000,75.2],[1414172834000,75.2],[1414172839000,75.2],[1414172844000,75.2],[1414172849000,75.2],[1414172854000,75.2],[1414172860000,75.2],[1414172865000,75.2],[1414172870000,75.2],[1414172875000,75.2],[1414172880000,75.2],[1414172885000,75.2],[1414172890000,75.2],[1414172895000,75.2],[1414172900000,75.2],[1414172905000,73.4],[1414172910000,75.2],[1414172916000,75.2],[1414172921000,75.2],[1414172926000,75.2],[1414172931000,75.2],[1414172936000,75.2],[1414172941000,75.2],[1414172946000,75.2],[1414172951000,75.2],[1414172956000,75.2],[1414172961000,75.2],[1414172966000,73.4],[1414172972000,75.2],[1414172977000,75.2],[1414172982000,73.4],[1414172987000,75.2],[1414172992000,75.2],[1414172997000,73.4],[1414173002000,75.2],[1414173007000,75.2],[1414173012000,75.2],[1414173017000,75.2],[1414173022000,75.2],[1414173028000,75.2],[1414173033000,75.2],[1414173038000,75.2],[1414173043000,75.2],[1414173048000,75.2],[1414173053000,75.2],[1414173058000,75.2],[1414173063000,71.6],[1414173068000,75.2],[1414173073000,75.2],[1414173079000,75.2],[1414173084000,75.2],[1414173089000,75.2],[1414173094000,75.2],[1414173099000,75.2],[1414173104000,75.2],[1414173109000,75.2],[1414173114000,75.2],[1414173119000,75.2],[1414173124000,75.2],[1414173129000,75.2],[1414173135000,75.2],[1414173140000,75.2],[1414173145000,75.2],[1414173150000,75.2],[1414173155000,75.2],[1414173160000,75.2],[1414173165000,75.2],[1414173170000,75.2],[1414173175000,75.2],[1414173180000,75.2],[1414173185000,75.2],[1414173191000,75.2],[1414173196000,75.2],[1414173201000,75.2],[1414173206000,75.2],[1414173211000,75.2],[1414173216000,75.2],[1414173221000,75.2],[1414173226000,75.2],[1414173231000,75.2],[1414173236000,75.2],[1414173241000,75.2],[1414173247000,75.2],[1414173252000,75.2],[1414173257000,75.2],[1414173262000,75.2],[1414173267000,75.2],[1414173272000,75.2],[1414173277000,75.2],[1414173282000,75.2],[1414173287000,75.2],[1414173292000,75.2],[1414173298000,75.2],[1414173303000,75.2],[1414173308000,75.2],[1414173313000,75.2],[1414173318000,75.2],[1414173323000,75.2],[1414173328000,75.2],[1414173333000,75.2],[1414173338000,75.2],[1414173343000,75.2],[1414173348000,75.2],[1414173354000,75.2],[1414173359000,75.2],[1414173364000,75.2],[1414173369000,75.2],[1414173374000,75.2],[1414173379000,75.2],[1414173384000,75.2],[1414173389000,75.2],[1414173394000,75.2],[1414173399000,75.2],[1414173404000,75.2],[1414173410000,75.2],[1414173415000,75.2],[1414173420000,75.2],[1414173425000,75.2],[1414173430000,75.2],[1414173435000,75.2],[1414173440000,75.2],[1414173445000,75.2],[1414173450000,75.2],[1414173455000,73.4],[1414173461000,75.2],[1414173466000,75.2],[1414173471000,75.2],[1414173476000,75.2],[1414173481000,75.2],[1414173486000,75.2],[1414173491000,75.2],[1414173496000,75.2],[1414173501000,73.4],[1414173506000,75.2],[1414173511000,75.2],[1414173517000,73.4],[1414173522000,75.2],[1414173527000,75.2],[1414173532000,75.2],[1414173537000,75.2],[1414173542000,75.2],[1414173547000,75.2],[1414173552000,73.4],[1414173557000,75.2],[1414173562000,75.2],[1414173567000,75.2],[1414173573000,75.2],[1414173578000,75.2],[1414173583000,75.2],[1414173590000,32],[1414173651000,75.2],[1414173711000,75.2],[1414173771000,73.4],[1414173831000,75.2],[1414173891000,73.4],[1414173951000,75.2],[1414174011000,73.4],[1414174071000,75.2],[1414174131000,73.4],[1414174191000,75.2],[1414174251000,71.6],[1414174311000,73.4],[1414174372000,73.4],[1414174432000,73.4],[1414174492000,73.4],[1414174552000,73.4],[1414174612000,73.4],[1414174672000,73.4],[1414174732000,73.4],[1414174792000,73.4],[1414174852000,73.4],[1414174912000,73.4],[1414174972000,73.4],[1414175032000,73.4],[1414175093000,73.4],[1414175153000,73.4],[1414175213000,73.4],[1414175273000,73.4],[1414175333000,73.4],[1414175393000,73.4],[1414175453000,73.4],[1414175513000,73.4],[1414175573000,73.4],[1414175633000,73.4],[1414175693000,73.4],[1414175753000,73.4],[1414175814000,73.4],[1414175874000,73.4],[1414175934000,73.4],[1414175994000,73.4],[1414176054000,73.4],[1414176114000,73.4],[1414176174000,73.4],[1414176234000,75.2],[1414176294000,75.2]]
```

Comment: Are you sure the data coming back from the server is the correct time? Is the SQL server set to use a different timezone? You should set the poperty to `useUTC: true` such that all data comes back from the server "as-is".

Comment: If I don't convert the timestamp to UNIX time and multiply by 1000 (to get millisecs for javascript) in the PHP script, the format from MySQL looks like this: ["2014-10-24 15:54:00",73.4],["2014-10-24 15:55:00",73.4] ...  I don't get any difference when I set that global option useUTC true of false.  The time's minutes/seconds look fine in Highcharts, its just the hours are consistently off by 4 hours.   I'm wondering if it's a timezone thing, but I'm not sure where that problem would be.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, not sure if this is the most elegant, but it is producing the correct results now.  It looks like when using the strtotime conversion in PHP, it was using the default GMT timezone.  In the PHP script, I added the date_default_time_set('UTC') and it works.  Hopefully this will help someone in the future.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","raspberry");

if (!$con) {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("xbee", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT time, temperature FROM data WHERE time >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    extract($r);
    $time = strtotime($r[0]);
    $time *=1000;
    $row[0] = $time;
    $row[1] = $r[1];
    array_push($rows,$row);
}

print json_encode($rows, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

mysql_close($con);
?>
```